# Type for const string array containing subset of string literal union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a string literal union type Animal:

```js
type Animal = 'GOAT' | 'GIRAFFE' | 'SALMON' | 'TUNA'
```

I also have a type Fish which is a subset of Animal:

```js
type Fish = Extract<Animal, 'SALMON' | 'TUNA'> // type Fish = "SALMON" | "TUNA"
```

Now I want to have an array of string containing the Fish, so that I can use that array in the logic (e.g. to use the `includes()` function).
I could just define the array separately:

```js
const FISH: ReadonlyArray<Fish> = ['SALMON', 'TUNA']
```

but now I have to maintain the list of fish in two places.

What I want to know is: **is it possible to use the values in the array to define which string literals to extract for the Fish type while also only allowing the array to contain Animal strings**?

Something like:

```js
const FISH: ReadonlyArray<SubsetOfStringLiterals<Animal>> = ['SALMON', 'TUNA'] // Would error if it contained a value not in Animal
type Fish = typeof FISH[number] // type Fish = "SALMON" | "TUNA"
```

where `SubsetOfStringLiterals` would essentially be a utility like `Partial` but for string literal union types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to apply a constraint to a type and also infer something more specific, then you need to either use a generic function or the new `satisfies` operator.

---

Coming in the next Typescript version (4.9, currently in beta) is [the `satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) which works nicely here.

```
// fine
const FISH = ['SALMON', 'TUNA'] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<Animal>

// error
const FISH_BAD = ['COFFEE'] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<Animal>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221024#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkBxAeRgBUcoAfXPASQCUYAxBgUTMpwGUYAZAWQIBybXMQCqAmDgBQU0JCgMEAZwAWWKMwAewAE4oAxsAA88ZOgA0uLn0HCcYiTgB8UAPSuoc6ItXqARNb8An4UUH4OMH4y+gD2cErACtQcABLqANqcPEE4lvbikgC6UChKULHxiUoowMoAZggQZbQQKAAmcWggMDp6ICaIqGhOUu5Q41AAegD8MlIVCUmpAPoAQjAAIhk4AMIETMysxaXlcYvVtUoNTVAt7Z3dvSj9pkMjQA)

---

Typescript 4.8 or below, you'll need to use a simple generic identity function.

```
function makeSubAnimals<T extends readonly Animal[]>(arr: T) { return arr }

const FISH = makeSubAnimals(['SALMON', 'TUNA'] as const) // fine
const FISH_BAD = makeSubAnimals(['COFFEE'] as const) // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkBxAeRgBUcoAfXPASQCUYAxBgUTMpwGUYAZAWQIBybXMQCqAmDgBQU0JCgMEAZwAWWKMwAewAE4oAxsAA88ZOgA0uLn0HCcYiTgB8UAPSuoc6ItXqARNb8An4UUH4OMH4yAGYArnCGCAD2cFCoANYQHLEARqaoaEpGxFAQ2hBwACZKUDoQKJUpaCCwiAUA2gC6TgAUKDo6AFxQxACUUADetRDAsTqp-TpQAL4y+ilKwArUHAAS6hlZufnoSj3tnDxBOJb24pKdUCg163Cbo1LuUN9QAHoA-DIpK9Nts9gB9ABCMAAIgcUJlsnk2qdzjgAMIEJjMViPZ5QEHAcZfCADJI6IA)

Comment: I don't know if OP wants a readonly tuple, as their original post annotates `FISH` as a readonly array. In any case, it's an easy fix; annotate the return type of `makeSubAnimals` with `Readonly<T>` and remove the `as const`.

Comment: The tuple `readonly ['a', 'b']` is assignable to `readonly ('a' | 'b')[]`, so I'm not sure it makes difference. The only difference is if you are indexing it with a numeric literal, which is assignable to the union of possible values, which also seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Alex Wayne's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74184098/20275210) (+1) would be to make the compiler infer the type of `FISH`, and then separately ensure that `Fish` is really a subtype of `Animal`.

For example:

```
type Animal = 'GOAT' | 'GIRAFFE' | 'SALMON' | 'TUNA'

const FISH = ['SALMON', 'TUNA'] as const;

type Fish = typeof FISH[number] // type Fish = "SALMON" | "TUNA"

// dead code, but fails to compile if you add a 'TROUT' to FISH
((f: Fish) : Animal => f)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkBxAeRgBUcoAfXPASQCUYAxBgUTMpwGUYAZAWQIBybXMQCqAmDgBQUgMYB7OAGdgUBtQ4AJLFADanHvyEAaEeMkBdKCiVQFy4AG4ZoSGoRKAFjtcR5AMzUNTV04AFckACMIACcrAHp4qF93Lx0AIi4+QXSKKHSxCXSZRKgAEwgUMrt5CtNIsNV-FAQ0W2B5GqQwVugEQJB5MOsy6pQRWgJRUmTO9S0pAApF-wAuVM8ASih1+GR0LAA+KH9NoA).

Comment: Well, same as my comment on Alex's answer, we don't know if OP wants a readonly tuple instead of a readonly array.

Answer (score 0):

No need for type casting:

```js
type Animal = 'GOAT' | 'GIRAFFE' | 'SALMON' | 'TUNA'
type Fish = Extract<Animal, 'SALMON' | 'TUNA'>
type ArrayOfFish = Array<Partial<Fish>>;

let arr: ArrayOfFish = ['SALMON']; // Accepts SALMON | TUNA
```